# interpret Jade as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, pug

I'm following a tutorial using Node, MongoDB and Jade. The problem is, Jade no longer works so I'm doing everything in .handlebars. (I've tried to npm pug to use instead of Jade, but pug will not work and I cannot figure out why).

The tutorial uses the follow Jade code to display info from the database onto the webpage:

```
extends layout

block content
  h3.
    Students
  ul
    each student, i in studentlist
      li#student_list_item
        a(href='#') #{student.student} lives at #{student.street} #{student.city}, #{student.state}
```

I guess my question is how to do that for-loop in the HTML doc so it can access the database.

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't work*? What's happening, what supposed to happen?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I npm install pug with no errors. I run a pug script like 'pug filename.pug' and it says that pug is not a valid command

Comment: @Seth here is the tutorial: http://www.newthinktank.com/2016/01/nodejs-mongodb-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The # should be an = shouldn't it?
I don't know a lot of jade but just looking on google, it seems like it should be

```
li= student_list_item
```

but not sure. Hope this help.

Comment: The # should be an = in HTML? The code is correct in Jade. I'm trying to put it into HTML.

Comment: I don't think you can put a for loop in html?

Comment: You have to use jade or ejs for that.

Comment: How do I do it in EJS?

Comment: <ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<studentList.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= studentList[i] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>